# Cannot access to my dyndns host when i am inside the network

Tags: networking, router, ip-camera, localconnection, dyndns

Router ip :  *`192.168.1.1`* 
Camera 1 ip :  *`192.168.1.80 port : 8000`* 
Camera 2 ip :  *`192.168.1.81 port : 8100`* 
Dyndns host :  *`test.dyndns.org`*

Firewall disable
upnp : enable
port fordward 8000 to  *`192.168.1.80`*  (both)
port fordward 8100 to  *`192.168.1.81`*  (both)

When i am connected to MY network : 
 *`http://192.168.1.80:8000` WORKING* 
 *`http://192.168.1.80:8000` WORKING*

When i am connected with 3g (or wifi to ANOTHER network e.g. my friend) i go to url -->  *`http://test.dyndns.org:8000`*  and camera WORKING.

When i am connected with wifi to MY network i go to url -->  *`http://test.dyndns.org:8000`*  and camera NOT WORKING.
NO URL FIND. CONNECTION REFUSED

Why i have this problem?

Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup NAT loopback on your router.  This allows you to connect to the WAN interface IP while you're on the LAN.  How you enable this will depend on what type of router you have.

You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback